# Add column to data frame with the distance to several points

Tags: python, geopy

I want to add a column to a dataframe with the distance to a several points.

```
import geopy.distance

point1 = (62.14501749692785, 15.489451406957805)
point2 = (61.18566746746592, 9.600779755097122)

def distancer(row, point):
  coords_1 = (row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])
  return geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(coords_1, point).km
```

My problem is how to define/call the function.

For example to add a column with the distance to `point1`:

```
dataset['dist_point1'] = dataset.apply(distancer(row=row, point = point1), axis=1)
dataset['dist_point2'] = dataset.apply(distancer(row=row, point = point2), axis=1)
```

Which is Not working because I can't pass the '`row`' argument to the function.

**EDIT**:

```
dataset['coords'] = list(zip(dataset['Latitude'], dataset['Longitude']))
dataset['dist_point1'] = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(dataset['coords'], point1).km
```

Is returning the error:

```
ValueError: When creating a Point from sequence, it must not have more than 3 items.
```

Comment: Can't you just do something like : `dataset['dist_point1'] = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(coords_1, point).km` ?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou thanks, but the distance funtion requires both arguments to be tuples

Comment: well I meant:

`point1 = (62.14501749692785, 15.489451406957805)

dataset['dist_point1'] = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance((row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']), point1).km`

Comment: It returns the error: NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Comment: sorry about that :

`point1 = (62.14501749692785, 15.489451406957805)  dataset['dist_point1'] = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance((dataset['Latitude'], dataset['Longitude']), point1).km`

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().